# Stack consistency error when compiling assets on FreeBSD

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, freebsd

I'm trying to deploy a Rails app on a FreeBSD server. However, when I try to compile the assets, I get this weird error:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
/home/user/site/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/therubyracer-freebsd-0.10.1/lib/v8/portal.rb:16: [BUG] Stack consistency error (sp: 231, bp: 232)
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-freebsd9.1]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0062 p:0033 s:0231 e:000231 METHOD /home/user/site/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/therubyracer-freebsd-0.10.1/lib/v8/portal.rb:16
c:0061 p:0007 s:0228 e:000227 METHOD /home/user/site/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/therubyracer-freebsd-0.10.1/lib/v8/portal.rb:22
c:0060 p:0009 s:0225 e:000224 METHOD /home/user/site/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/therubyracer-freebsd-0.10.1/lib/v8/function.rb:25
c:0059 p:0013 s:0221 e:000220 METHOD /home/user/site/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/commonjs-0.2.7/lib/commonjs/environment.rb:28
c:0058 p:0022 s:0218 e:000217 METHOD /home/user/site/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/commonjs-0.2.7/lib/commonjs/module.rb:10 [FINISH]
c:0057 p:---- s:0213 e:000212 CFUNC  :new
c:0056 p:0100 s:0208 e:000205 METHOD /home/user/site/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/commonjs-0.2.7/lib/commonjs/environment.rb:17
c:0055 p:0045 s:0199 e:000198 LAMBDA /home/user/site/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/commonjs-0.2.7/lib/commonjs/module.rb:18 [FINISH]
c:0054 p:---- s:0194 e:000193 CFUNC  :call
c:0053 p:0034 s:0189 e:000188 BLOCK  /home/user/site/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/therubyracer-freebsd-0.10.1/lib/v8/portal/caller.rb:32
c:0052 p:0006 s:0187 e:000186 METHOD /home/user/site/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/therubyracer-freebsd-0.10.1/lib/v8/portal/caller.rb:11
c:0051 p:0014 s:0182 e:000180 METHOD /home/user/site/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/therubyracer-freebsd-0.10.1/lib/v8/portal/caller.rb:26
...
```

The stacktrace goes far on. I can paste all of it, if it helps. After it, it says:

```
[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
```

Did I really find a Ruby bug? I hardly think so. The assets are compiled successfully on Ubuntu. I googled about it (a lot) and didn't find anything.

I think it may be something with the `therubyracer` gem. I'm using the `therubyracer-freebsd` gem, but I've already tried both, the error doesn't go away.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like an issue in therubyracer. You can install node.js and remove this gem from your Gemfile.

Follow this: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#freebsd-and-openbsd

Comment: I tried. When I do that, it says "please add 'therubyracer' to your Gemfile". It looks like `less-rails` depends on it. Or `twitter-bootstrap-rails`. Or both, don't know for sure.

Comment: Not according to the gemspec: https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/blob/master/twitter-bootstrap-rails.gemspec#L34

Comment: I removed `therubyracer` and it says "Please install gem 'therubyracer' to use Less". Well, I got rid of Less and switched to Sass. The problem went away :D

Answer (score 0):

Mostly [therubyracer](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer) gem issue. Try `bundle update therubyracer`, if you are using bundler, which shall update any dependency issue. Worked for me.